# audit does not record file events (but works for network events) in fedora

Tags: fedora, audit, linux-audit

I want to monitor access to a file using audit, and hence added the following rule

```
-w /home/test.txt -k monitoring-test
```

I reloaded the rules (`sudo service auditd restart`) and modified the file `/home/test.txt`, however, the log does not create any events with that key: `sudo ausearch -k monitoring-test` returns only the event of adding the rule:

```
time->Fri May  5 13:32:19 2023 type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1682311231.581:1719): auid=1000 ses=3 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 op=add_rule key="monitoring-test" list=4 res=1
```

Strangely, when adding a network monitoring rule like

> -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S accept,connect -F key=network-external-access

I do get log messages with the corresponding key.

I read multiple posts like [this tutorial](https://ayedaemon.github.io/post/2022/12/recording_system_events_with_auditd/) or that [redhat post](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10107) but none of their solution fixes my problem. Does anyone see why I do not get any logs for editing the file?

The Kernel has the following flags, obtained by

> sudo grep CONFIG_AUDIT /boot/config-`uname -r`

```
CONFIG_AUDIT=y
CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL=y
CONFIG_AUDIT_ARCH=y
```

Is it a problem that CONFIG_AUDIT_WATCH=y is missing, which is present in the [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507393/299567)?

---

For the record, my /etc/audit/audit.rules is (after adding the above file monitor rule permanently):

```
 ## This file is automatically generated from /etc/audit/rules.d
 -D
 
 
 -a task,never
 -w /home/test.txt -k monitoring-test
```

And `sudo auditctl -l` returns

```
-a never,task
-w /home/test.txt -p rwxa -k monitoring-test
```

My operating system is Fedora, and the audit version is 3.1-2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`auditctl` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/auditd/auditctl.8.en.html):

> DISABLED BY DEFAULT
>
> **On many systems `auditd` is configured to install an `-a never,task` rule by default.** This rule causes every new process to skip all audit rule processing. This is usually done to avoid a small performance  overhead  imposed by syscall auditing. If you want to use `auditd`, you need to remove that rule by deleting `10-no-audit.rules` and adding `10-base-config.rules` to the audit rules directory.
>
> If you have defined audit rules that are not matching when they should, check `auditctl -l` to  make sure there is no `never,task` rule there.

This is because the event triggers on the first matching rule.

Remove first rule `-a never,task`.

Comment: Why did the network rule work nonetheless? Because networking is not considered task-related?

Comment: because the first rule takes precedence over the ones following, and first one doesn't have specified what tasks to ignore, so it causes all created to be ignored. Basically it causes so auditd don't have to parse all syscalls created. https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/master/rules/10-no-audit.rules